# How to combine multiple html tables into One final html file

Tags: python

we have few dataframes dfInsu1 & dfInsu2 and tried converting into html

```
print(dfInsu1)

InsuranceId InsuranceName
123456      Ravi


print(dfInsu2)

FinanceTrId FinanciarName
567899      Ram

htmltab1 = dfInsu1.to_html(index=False) 
htmltab2 = dfInsu2.to_html(index=False)
```

After then we have added colors to above html tables

```
header='''<html>
<head>
<style>
table.dataframe {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color-color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

headforInsur='''<html> 
<body>     <h1 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;position: absolute;border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;">Insurance:</h1>
</body>
'''

headforFin='''<html> 
<body>     <h1 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;position: absolute;border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;">Finance: </h1>
</body>
'''
```

we are trying to apply header colors for both the dataframes..

We are able to send the above contents in email by summing as below

```
email = headforInsur + header + htmltab1 + headforFin + header + htmltab2 (Here colors are getting applied in header)
```

Can we combine all the above concent into one html file (headforInsur + header + htmltab1 + headforFin + header + htmltab2) and get in same format and create a final one html file ?

Comment: @Tried searching all the urls, pls help me to know if any link i can refer and try